# How to implement regex to react on change Event?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, reactjs

I am creating form validation and one of my input is `type='text'` but I need to allow user to write there only digits from 0-9 and max number length 9. Can I pass there any regex to eliminate letters from input value before It is pass to state?

```
const handleChangeData = ({currentTarget}, key) => {
let val = currentTarget.value;

if (currentTarget.name === 'phone') {
      const regex = /d+/;
      val.match(regex);
      changeData(prevState => {
        return {...prevState, [key]: val};
      });
    }
// ... more code here
}
```

I don't want to use `type=number` and I can't use `patters` because I have my own errors popups.

html:

```
<div className="form-control">
  {errors.phone && (
    <div style={{left: '-275.38px'}} className="error">
      {errors.phone}
    </div>
  )}
  <label htmlFor="phone">
    <i className="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>
  </label>
  <input
    value={data.phone}
    id="phone"
    name="phone"
    onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
    onChange={e => handleChangeData(e, 'phone')}
    type="text"
    placeholder="Numer telefonu"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand your code. You overwrite `val` with the regex instead of applying the regex to the `val` and checking if the result is valid? What should the state be set to when valid? and what when invalid? Since as written, you set the new value of state property `phone` to the regex `/(d+)/`.

Comment: Edited code with regex for you

Comment: I want to block writing letters, only digits needs to be put inside state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the `onKeyPress` event.

Use below code to handle the validation.

```
const validateNumber = (evt, regex) => {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Call above method `onKeyPress` of `input` element

```
onKeyPress = (e) => { validateNumber(e, /[0-9]|\./) }
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Not all your code but reg.test() almost did work for me, and regex should be /^\d+$/;

Comment: Thank you!, You mean to say key press is not working for you.

Comment: I am not saying that is not working, look on my html see what structure I have

Answer (score 1):

```js
const handlePhoneChange = ({ currentTarget, key, keyCode }) => {
  // Since this will trigger on every key, we only need to check
  // if the key that was pressed is a digit.
  // We could use a regexp on the value.
  // Or check the key
  // Or check the keyCode
  
  // 1) RegExp
  // We test that between the beginning and the end of the value, there are between 1 and 9 digits
  const is_valid = /^\d{1,9}$/.test( currentTarget.value );
  
  // 2) key
  // const is_valid = [0123456789].includes( key ) && currentTarget.value.length <= 9;
  
  // 3) keyCode
  //const is_valid = keycode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105 && currentTarget.value.length <= 9;;
  
  // Update the state. If the typed character is a valid digit
  // the new state is the full value
  // Else it remains the previous valid value, without the character just typed
  changeData( prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    phone: is_valid
      ? currentTarget.value
      : currentTarget.value.slice( 0, -1 )
  }));
};

// Event binding mockup, this would do react for you through onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
document.querySelector( '#phone' ).addEventListener( 'keyup', handlePhoneChange );

// changeData mockup, react would also do this for you
const changeData = reducer => {
  const state = reducer();
  document.querySelector( '#phone' ).value = state.phone;
};
```

```html
<input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Numer telefonu" type="text" value="">
```